Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS fingerprint support for HP Pavilion Laptop 15-egxxx [04f3:0c00]
I read many articles but couldnt get my fingerprint working. Pls help me to get it working.
┌──(rtk-rnjn㉿ubuntu2204)-[~]
└─$ neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               rtk-rnjn@ubuntu2204 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------------- 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: HP Pavilion Laptop 15-eg2xxx 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 6.5.0-27-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 58 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 2367 (dpkg), 16 (flatpak), 19 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: zsh 5.8.1 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1920x1080 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   DE: GNOME 42.9 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   WM: Mutter 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   WM Theme: Kali-Dark 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Theme: Kali-Dark [GTK2/3] 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/    Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3] 
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+     Terminal: gnome-terminal 
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/      CPU: 12th Gen Intel i5-1240P (16) @ 4.400GHz 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       GPU: Intel Alder Lake-P 
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-         Memory: 4333MiB / 15652MiB 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.                                       
                                                                   

┌──(rtk-rnjn㉿ubuntu2204)-[~]
└─$ lsusb   
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 04f3:0c00 Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:ARM-M4
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 30c9:0065 Luxvisions Innotech Limited HP Wide Vision HD Camera
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 13d3:3567 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

┌──(rtk-rnjn㉿ubuntu2204)-[~]
└─$ fprintd-enroll 
Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available

